# How to detect different types of PDF

Tags: java, pdf

A PDF file extension can be verified by the magic signature: `25 50 44 46`

However, I want to detect whether a PDF contains text or image (i.e. whether the PDF contains text that can be searched with ctrl+f OR whether it contains scanned documents)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: iText, PDFBox, and other Java PDF libraries, too, offer capabilities to extract text or images from PDF files. Use these capabilities of one of them and find some criteria when to consider a PDF scanned without OCR (e.g. not more than 50 non-whitespace characters on the page but at least 50% of the page covered with images).

Comment: This seems like a good technique. I will try iText

Answer (score 1):

Well technically, you could parse the PDF document structure and look for elements that contain text. I imagine this would require a big effort to implement.

So you may want to use a premade PDF package to do the parsing for you (PDFBox, BfoPDF or something similar). Still, I think it will require some effort to implement.

The simplest way that I know of would be to use a package that can extract the plain text for you. Apache TIKA can do this. Just feed it the document and see if you get something back.

In any case it will be hard to classify PDF's that contain both images and text.